# Vector Algebra Identity with escalar triple product

Tags: linear-algebra

How do i prove the following identity with indicial notation:

$\vec{a}(\vec{d}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c}))+\vec{b}(\vec{d}\cdot(\vec{c}\times\vec{a}))+\vec{c}(\vec{d}\cdot(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}))=\vec{d}(\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c}))$

i use the levi-civita symbol and i get the following expresión:

$\epsilon_{mjk}a_id_mb_jc_k+\epsilon_{mjk}b_id_mc_ja_k+\epsilon_{mjk}c_id_ma_jb_k$

for the left part of the equation, but i dont know what to do here

Answer (score 1):

For the cult use the "determinant way":

$$\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b} = \text{det}\begin{pmatrix}
\hat i & \hat j & \hat k\\
a_x & a_y & a_z\\
b_x & sb_y & b_z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then it's just about a bit of time and will.

I remember you the scalar product is instead

$$\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b} = a_xb_x + a_yb_y + a_zb_z$$